# Largest eigenvalue of matrix and the largest eigenvalue of its submatrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Why the largest eigenvalue of matrix is more than or equal to the largest eigenvalue of its submatrix?

If $A$ is $n \times n$ symetric matrix  and $A'$ is $n-1 \times n-1$ its submatrix
why is true $\lambda_{max}(A)\ge \lambda_{max}(A')$?
I don't know how to figure it out.

Comment: The statement only holds when $A$ is symmetric (or Hermitian if you're allowing complex entries); please add this to your post.  Also, please provide some context.  For instance, how did you come across this question?  What are your thoughts on it? What have you tried?

Comment: This can be seen as a consequence of the [Cauchy interlacing theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem) but can also be more simply proven directly using the Rayleigh-Ritz theorem.

Comment: and is there any other way? i didn't have numerical methods

Comment: The most straightforward approach is to use the Rayleigh-Ritz theorem.  I don't know what this has to do with "numerical methods".

Comment: By the way: something like "I would like to avoid using [certain kind of method]" is exactly the kind of thing that you would include in the context of your question, which is the thing that I keep asking you to add to your questions